# Get the last entry position easily?

Tags: c#, list, .net-4.0

What is the best or easier container I could use to retrieve the the last entry position ?

Or there are not better or easier than using Count ? is it ok to rely on count ?

Example:

```
List<Class> myList = new List<Class>();
int lastEntry = myList.Count - 1;
Message.Box(myList[lastEntry].Name);
```

**There is no concurrent write to this list mainly reading.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx) is fine for [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) -- or anything else that implements [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) or [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx) -- but you have an [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) in your code. It should be...

```
int lastEntry = myList.Count - 1;    // index is zero-based
```

Comment: yeah my bad was writing in a rush and might have left some misses, so using count would be the fastest way and yet simple and available for most list types ?

Comment: @Guapo: Everything that implements `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection` has a `Count` property.

Answer (score 2):

Count is going to be the most performant, though since list indexing is zero-based you'll want to use `count - 1` to retrieve the last entry in the list.

If you really want you can use Linq and do something like:

```
myList.Last()
```

or, if your worried about empty lists

```
myList.LastOrDefault()
```

But that is going to most likely be slower (depending on how Last() is implemented)

Comment: Might be worth adding in .LastOrDefault() to consider 0 length Lists.

Comment: Thanks....thought about that when I started answering the question..forgot about it by the time I finished.  Life with ADD :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Last](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549138.aspx), which can help you avoid erros like the one you made.

On a side-note: `Last` is optimised for `IList` implementations to use exactly the same method as you did: access with index. Sure it is probably slower than doing it manually (optimisation requires additional cast), but unless it really is a bottleneck I wouldn't worry too much.

If you're interested to investigate this topic deeper, here's part of Jon Skeet's excellent series: [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 11 - First/Single/Last and the ...OrDefault versions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/29/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-11-first-single-last-and-the-ordefault-versions.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of the `Last()` extension method like so:

```
Message.Box(myList.Last().Name);
```

Comment: yes but that would iterate thought the entire list, inst it ?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of `Last`, which I am not sure of.  It could be smart enough to use `Count` on collections that support it, and falling back to enumeration if it only implements `IEnumerable` (that is the way I would have implemented it).

Comment: @NathanAnderson: that's exactly how it's implemented - it uses index access for `IList` and regular iteration-based approach for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to access the last item in the list, you might be better off using a `Stack<T>` instead.  For the code you've written, there's nothing wrong with using Count - bear in mind that you should use `.Count - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Use a Stack:

```
Stack<Class> d = new Stack<Class>();
Class last = d.Pop();
Message.Box(last.Name);
```

or if you don't want to remove:

```
  Class last = d.Peek();
    Message.Box(last.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to make one point that seems to have been glossed over. Lists are not Queues; you don't always add to the end. You can instead Insert to them. If you want the index of the last-inserted item, you have to get a little more creative:

```
public class SmartList<T>:List<T>
{
   public int LastIndex {get; protected set;}   

   public new virtual void Add(T obj)
   {
      base.Add(obj);
      lastIndex = Count - 1;
   }

   public new virtual void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> obj)
   {
      base.AddRange(obj);
      lastIndex = Count - 1;
   }

   public new virtual void Insert(T obj, int index)
   {
      base.Insert(obj, index);
      lastIndex = index;
   }
}
```

Unfortunately List's methods are not virtual, so you have to hide them and thus you have to use this class as the concrete SmartList; you can't use it as the value of a List-typed variable or parameter.